# Lost Singapore entrance visa

Tags: visas, singapore

I'm from Saudi Arabia and got a Singapore visa on a paper but I didn't stick it on my passport. So when I got back from Singapore I noted that I've lost the visa. Can I apply for a new one?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have no other choice

Comment: By "on paper", do you mean a notification about receiving an electronic visa?

Comment: No, I got the Visa stuck on a paper delivered from Singapore.

But I just got an email from Singapore that says I can apply for a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the Singapore embassy in Riyadh and give the passport number and date of birth. They will give a reference number. Go to ICA save page, enter the details and you will get a copy there.